# Programmatically toggle resize of NSSplitViewItems

Tags: objective-c, macos, nssplitview, nssplitviewcontroller

I am trying to find a way to programmatically resize `NSSplitViewItems`.

Say the `NSWindow` frame size is 500x500px.
`masterViewItem` has a width of 100px, while `subViewItem` has a width of 400px.

When `FOO`, I want `masterViewItem` to collapse to 0px (towards the left),
while `subViewItem` expands to fill the entire window (500px).

When `BAR`, I want `masterViewItem` to expand back to 100px, while `subViewItem` collapses back to the original 400px.

```
- (IBAction) onTapOnSomeButton:(NSButton *)sender {

    NSWindow *window = [[NSApplication sharedApplication] mainWindow];
    NSSplitViewController *splitViewController = (NSSplitViewController *)[window contentViewController];
    NSSplitViewItem *masterViewItem =[splitViewController.splitViewItems firstObject];
    NSSplitViewItem *subViewItem = [splitViewController.splitViewItems lastObject];
    if (FOO) {
        [NSAnimationContext runAnimationGroup:^(NSAnimationContext *context) {
            //    Expand subViewItem 
        } completionHandler:^{
        }];
    } else if (BAR) {
        [NSAnimationContext runAnimationGroup:^(NSAnimationContext *context) {
            //    Expand masterViewItem while shrinking subViewItem
        } completionHandler:^{
        }];
    }
}
```

I am able to animate each item so that it seems to collapse/expand,
i.e.

```
subViewItem.viewController.view.animator.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, window.frame.size.width, subViewItem.viewController.view.frame.size.height);
```

but the divider will not move, making the two items just move individually, and does not look like the entire screen is collapsing/expanding.

How would I implement this? Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE**

So I have done a bit more research, and found this:

[How to animate the NSSplitView while resizing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11223267/how-to-animate-the-nssplitview-while-resizing?rq=1)

So I made code like this:

```
- (IBAction) onTapOnSomeButton:(NSButton *)sender {
    NSWindow *window = [[NSApplication sharedApplication] mainWindow];
    NSSplitViewController *splitViewController = (NSSplitViewController *)[window contentViewController];
    NSSplitViewItem *masterViewItem =[splitViewController.splitViewItems firstObject];
    NSSplitViewItem *subViewItem = [splitViewController.splitViewItems lastObject];
    if (FOO) {
         NSMutableDictionary *collapseMainAnimationDict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithCapacity:2];
         [collapseMainAnimationDict setObject: subView forKey:NSViewAnimationTargetKey];
         NSRect newRightSubViewFrame = subView.frame;
         newRightSubViewFrame.size.width =  splitViewController.splitView.frame.size.width;
         [collapseMainAnimationDict setObject:[NSValue valueWithRect:newRightSubViewFrame] forKey:NSViewAnimationEndFrameKey];

         NSMutableDictionary *collapseInspectorAnimationDict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithCapacity:2];
         [collapseInspectorAnimationDict setObject: masterView forKey:NSViewAnimationTargetKey];
         NSRect newLeftSubViewFrame = masterView.frame;
         newLeftSubViewFrame.size.width = 0.0f;
         newLeftSubViewFrame.origin.x = splitViewController.splitView.frame.size.width;
         [collapseInspectorAnimationDict setObject:[NSValue valueWithRect:newLeftSubViewFrame] forKey:NSViewAnimationEndFrameKey];

         NSViewAnimation *collapseAnimation = [[NSViewAnimation alloc] initWithViewAnimations:[NSArray arrayWithObjects: collapseMainAnimationDict, collapseInspectorAnimationDict, nil]];
         [collapseAnimation setDuration:0.3f];
         [collapseAnimation startAnimation];
         [splitViewController.splitView adjustSubviews];
         [splitViewController.splitView setNeedsDisplay: YES];
    } else if (BAR) {
        // Not yet implemented
    }
}
```

But to no effect. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You have to resize the panes using [`[NSSplitView setPosition:ofDividerAtIndex:]`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSSplitView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSSplitView/setPosition:ofDividerAtIndex:).

I have no idea what `NSSplitViewController` is, but presumably you can get access to the `NSSplitView` via its `view` property, or some such.

Comment: Thanks. So in my case, I tried `[splitViewController.splitView setPosition:1000.0f ofDividerAtIndex: 0];`, but nothing is happening. Any advice?

Comment: @NaotoIda No, I've got nothing.

Comment: @NaotoIda However why are you using a position of `1000.0f`?

Comment: It was just to see how it would act.

Comment: But it's bigger than the frame size.  Perhaps try something more realistic first?

Comment: I tried `10.0f`, but nothing is happening. Could this be do to the `masterViewItem` having a specified size?

Comment: @NaotoIda There are several methods used to configure the split view; you might need to use them to configure the correct behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than looking at it as a resize, it sounds like you're simply trying to collapse/uncollapse the master view item. You can just use `NSSplitViewItem`'s `collapsed` property with its `animator` proxy to trigger the collapse:

```
    if (FOO) {
        //    Expand subViewItem (collapse the master view item)
        masterViewItem.animator.collapsed = YES;
```

And uncollapse:

```
    } else if (BAR) {
        //    Expand masterViewItem while shrinking subViewItem
        masterViewItem.animator.collapsed = NO;
    }
}
```

With 10.11, there's API to designate your master view item as a "sidebar", which has additional collapse/uncollapse behavior for that item (such as overlays).

Comment: Thanks. I have tried that, but cannot find the correct code to expand the width of `subViewItem.viewController.view`, while retaining the overall window size. Any suggestions?

Comment: That should happen automatically/be controlled by the `holdingPriority` of the subViewItem (which is the priority the split view holds the items at their current size) and any other constraints you have in it. If the `holdingPriority` is less than `NSLayoutPriorityWindowSizeStayPut` (500), and there are no other constraints that would prevent it from growing larger, then it will as the master item collapses.

Comment: Sorry, I'm taking over someone else's work, so I'm confused in some parts. There was a self.preferredContentSize set, and by removing it, I could collapse the masterViewItem without changing the width of the window, but there is not animation when subViewItem fills the void.